# How can I add ICON similar delete ICON in views on CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to add an icon to a view in CRM – similar to how they now have a delete icon when you hover over a record but we would want the icon to be available all the times based on the status or other factors.

Comment: AFAIK you can't change the inner structure of CRM parts

Answer (score 1):

The supported method is to add a ribbon button.  I find this tool to be helpful: http://www.develop1.net/public/Download%20Ribbon%20Workbench%202013.aspx